# webpack 4 - app not loading at root in production mode

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have nothing fancy about my `webpack.config.js` file.

More or less the minimum required to get my react app running.

Everything loads fine the way it should in dev mode, with webpack-dev-server.

However, for some reason I can't explain, it does not in production mode. It will load at /dist/

```
entry: './src/index.js',
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist')
}
```

Are we supposed to define 2 output paths for dev and prod modes ? I have checked several online tutorials, all config files seem to be standard and have the same configuration I came up with as above.

The second problem I have, which may be related, is npm run build won't build my dist folder. The terminal will show no error message. Everything compiles fine, I can see my bundle.js file and all. However, no dist folder. If I create a dist/ folder, it won't create the relevant files in it.

Nothing fancy with my scripts either :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --config ./webpack.config.js" 
  }
```

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue , because I am also facing the same issue